# Troubles with compiling with FLTK framework

Tags: c++, mingw, fltk

I seem to have problems compiling FLTK programms using anything other than the fltk-config script.

I have copied the source from the "Hello world" program in the tutorial. When I run fltk-config --compile hello.cpp it prints out

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -mwindows -DWIN32 -DUSE_OPENGL32 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE32_SOURCE -o 'hello' 'hello.cpp' -mwindows /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a -lole32 -luuid -lcomct132
```

and compiles just fine. But when I print in the same thing myself, it says, that ld.exe cannot find -lcomct132.

I use FLTK 1.3.0 compiled on MinGW under WinXP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that the fltk-config script is setting environment variables that you have not configured. Check the FLTK documentation and see the proper environment variables you need to set to compile without the helper script.

**Edit:** Did some research

Apparently you're not the only one that has linking problems. I found a similar problem on the forum [here](http://www.gidforums.com/t-15747.html) and on the [fltk.general](http://www.mail-archive.com/fltk@easysw.com/msg10576.html) newsgroup. The consensus seems to be that order of the linking arguments are important, and that using the fltk-config script is the easiest way to proceed.

Comment: I have double checked the documentation, but haven't found anything about environment variables under windows there. Unfortunately, I don't know much about shell scripts, so I can't understand if it really does set any environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get this specific error, but I did have problem with the "lcomct132". Maybe your error has something related to it. So, in my case, here it was the SOLUTION:

- The "132" is in fact only "32". The "1" isn't a number but smallcase letter L. So it is "lcomctl32" !